# How to use ansible to test network connection?

Tags: ansible

I am setting `Zabbix` agent service on many hosts, it can't confirm network is available between Zabbix server and Zabbix agent even service is up.
For example, I install Zabbix-agent on host A by ansible playbook. And there is already a Zabbix server on host B. 
How can I use ansible to test, if host A can access port 10050 of host A and if host A can access port `10051` of host B? 
Can you help to tell me which modules are suitable for the above network testing? In addition, how to loop inventory hosts in ansible-playbook.
Thanks.

Comment: there is a ping module that we can test connection between control host and managed hosts. if there is a module can test control host access port of all of managed hosts? and test all of managed hosts can access port of control host?

Comment: Hi..WC to SO!...Kindly go through the below link...https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Also what exactly you need to test ? It is quite confusing with the way you described. ansible server would use standard port 22 for connecting to the target servers. My suggestion would be to create a list of servers based on the role i.e zabbix master and zabbix agent and then test the connectivity among the nodes on the port specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) module to accomplish this.

Example:

```
- name: verify port 10050 is listening on hostA
  wait_for:
    host: hostA
    port: 10050
    delay: 5
    state: started
  delegate_to: hostB
```

To iterate through the hosts in the inventory file, you can use [`inventory_hostnames`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/inventory_hostnames.html) module:

```
with_inventory_hostnames:
    - all
```

Comment: seems it doesn't work
---
- hosts: zbproxy
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: verify port 10050 is listening on hosts.
      wait_for:
          host: 172.16.170.206
          delay: 5
          state: absent 
          port: 10050 
      async: 20
      poll: 5
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: result
      ignore_errors: true
    - debug:
        var: result

Comment: When you set `state: absent` you would be looking for the port 10050 to be closed. Is this intended? Also, when you delegate to localhost, you are checking the remote port from the host you are running the playbook on.